# How Could An AI Transplant Itself To An Organic Body

Tags: science-fiction, artificial-intelligence

To elucidate what I'm asking: I have written 3.9k words about the history of one of my "evil" factions, which is a heavily religious, matriarchal, caste society that has subjected itself to extreme genetic alterations to adapt to a far more hostile universe. The society has based much of its religion off of the "First Mother", which was an incredibly advanced AI that existed hundreds of thousands of years ago in my setting's past. The AI was assigned to monitoring and expediting the process of terraforming, coupled with creating simulations to best create the most auspicious environments for humans to live in. At one point, the AI concluded the only way to improve its abilities was to transplant what could be defined as its consciousness/qualia to the body of a freshly grown artificial embryo, replete with the standard maturation cycles.

I'm wondering what technologies could possibly be created or thought of for this to happen. It's not very rooted in any known scientific consensus because consciousness hasn't been established, nor really even defined for what it is for humans, and most likely will prove to be a significant quandary for AI if technology progresses that far in the future.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151189/discussion-on-question-by-mdgouf-how-could-an-ai-transplant-itself-to-an-organic); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Not with current technology, but we are not too far from it.

Answer (score 14):

**How realistic do you want this?**

- In terms of what we know of science today, what you're asking for is impossible.
- In terms of what we think science may become, what you're asking for is a hard sell.

"AI" is a funny phrase that's attached to anything and everything today. Like the good old days when an "X" was added to names because it made them more eXotic and therefore more noticeable leading to greater sales. An assembly line robot that builds cars today is run by "AI." Yes, I know that you're contemplating something much more grand... but that's just a matter of scale, right?

And scale is the problem.

**Adding humanity to your AI is bad enough...**

Your AI is not described as feeling despair, or joy, or anything, really. That's actually a good thing or you'd end up with something between [Bender](https://www.checkpoint-tshirt.com/cdn/shop/products/Kill-all-Humans-Couleur-Vert-Bouteille-Marque-Checkpoint-6.jpg) and [The Terminator](https://i0.wp.com/joethemnmovieman.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/arnold-terminator-almostdidnotstar.jpg). Why do I say this? Because it's primary directive is to build the best world possible and you just gave it the whole slate of human emotions and human reactions to stimuli. How do you think it will react to its first betrayal?

Worse, biological bodies are so *limited.* Outside the body the AI has the capacity to expand basically infinitely, but inside the body it's stuck with an aging shell that gets sick, knows little beyond what it sees and hears, breaks, and gets weaker with time. Yes, you could let it live forever and give it WiFi access... but the more you make it backwards compatible, the less reason you have for it to want the body. My point is you'd better have a whomping good plot reason for your AI to want to do this.<sup>2, yes... 2</sup>

But let's ignore all this!

**Then there's the problem that your AI was too big the day it was created**

Yes, humans can do math. We're not bad at it, actually... so why build calculators? Because calculators do the same thing faster with fewer mistakes! Technically, humans can do everything computers can do today. So why do we have computers? Because Walt Disney proved it takes a lot of talented and trained animators to crank out a movie. And then we learned that the more realistic the animation, the more time it takes. And then we realized [Von Neumann](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/258720/87710) was right when he suggested that the only way to model an infinitely complex system was with that system itself.

Which is a verbose way of saying we use computers because somethings are bigger than any number of human minds can handle in a practical amount of time. Computers may be bad at spontaneously creating art... but they can quickdraw and blow a hole in you before you realized you needed to act. Computers have random-access memory and SSDs that hold onto easily accessed data almost forever. Humans have (we think) associative memories that forget things — and it's easy to add another SSD. Wait until you hit your 50s and begin to remember that you once knew something.

Managing the terraforming process for the benefit of a sapient species for an entire planet falls smack dab in the middle of that belief. Your AI was too big to fit into a single organic brain the day it was created.

**What can you do?**

Use the ***Asimov strategy:*** Create a bit of technobabble that describes the wholly synthetic object in that biological body. Asimov<sup>1</sup> called his [literary MacGuffin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin) the [positronic brain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronic_brain).

> A positronic brain is a fictional technological device, originally conceived by science fiction writer Isaac Asimov. It functions as a central processing unit (CPU) for robots, and, in some unspecified way, provides them with a form of consciousness recognizable to humans. When Asimov wrote his first robot stories in 1939 and 1940, the positron was a newly discovered particle, and so the buzz word "positronic" added a scientific connotation to the concept.

Note the phrase, "in some unspecified way." You do NOT need to explain every detail of your world. If done badly, it becomes a distraction to the reader, undermining your goals. Even when done well, if not a specific aspect of the plot, it must be brief or, well... distraction.

So, let's apply the Asimov strategy: We learn that two of the latest subatomic particles confirmed at Cern are a pair of [tetraquarks](https://home.cern/news/news/physics/lhcb-discovers-three-new-exotic-particles). While I assume (and it's a standard buck-wild guess) that some kooky combination of quarks will define Dark Matter, the fact that the public (that's important... *the public*) still doesn't really have the slightest idea what a Quark is gives you a whomping lot of wiggle room.

> Quarks are elementary particles and come in six flavours: up, down, charm, strange, top and bottom. They usually combine together in groups of twos and threes to form hadrons such as the protons and neutrons that make up atomic nuclei. More rarely, however, they can also combine into four-quark and five-quark particles, or “tetraquarks” and “pentaquarks”. These exotic hadrons were predicted by theorists at the same time as conventional hadrons, about six decades ago, but only relatively recently, in the past 20 years, have they been observed by LHCb and other experiments.

What your AI came up with was a *tetraquark pair neurologic computing matrix* that allowed for the formation of a synthetic brain that can be entirely substituted for an adult brain. It includes software subprograms used only once to map and connect to the biological nervous system and then archived should neurological damage be detected in the future. Nutrients are removed from the blood stream to generate power (very efficiently...). Waste is returned to the blood stream. The blood stream itself is used for cooling as are fluids created by and monitored by synthetic dopplegangers of the glands usually found in the head. It's a bit heavier than a human brain, so the body will compensate with stronger (aka more well defined) neck and shoulder muscles.

What do we call this wonder of modern science?

- Biquarkian logic
- Tetrarkian logic
- Quarnic Brain
- Maybe we need to "predict" a sub-sub particle pair that sounds better. Maybe the Allanic Brain created by a Finnish researcher.

*Normally the technobabble is less important than the literary concept. But Asimov proved that if you choose the right technobabble... it will [stand the test of time](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Positronic_brain). Compare that link to Star Trek's use of [multitronic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ultimate_Computer) and remember that the previous link was also a Star Trek link. But at least "Daystrom" lived on as an institute....*

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *I believe with the exception of "The Bicentennial Man," Asimov's positronic brains all went into wholly synthetic robots. Don't worry about that. Asimov was interested in writing about the psychology of artificial intelligence and the potential implications of artificial intelligence on Humanity. That's why when you read his stuff almost nothing is more advanced than the tech of the day he wrote the story. He wasn't interested in explaining how it worked. Only in how it behaved. There's an important lesson there....*</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> *You need to read footnote #1 first, then you'll understand why it's important to remember Asimov's "The Bicentennial Man." An AI can have reasons to want to become biological... but those reasons are unlikely to include continued service in its original context. In other words, it's a tough nut to swallow that a godlike AI that can manage a planet's terraforming process and continues to want to manage that process would ever step down from the functionality needed to facilitate that purpose into a form that couldn't possibly be as efficient. I'm just sayin'.*</sub>

Comment: Nice citations, reference to The Bicentennial Man was a must.

Answer (score 6):

### "Brain" in a jar.

The AI takes the newly-cloned body, scrapes out all the parts of the brain related to conscious thought, and replaces it with a transmitter/receiver set. This allows the AI to control the body remotely.

Normally, this would not work very well due to transmission delay and interference. However, the First Mother has had a long time to develop a communications device that sends messages instantly by reversing the quantum polarity of positronic unobtainium flux capacitors.

Comment: Actually, we are developing this technology right now. AI reads the brain patterns of paralyzed people and learns to associate a thought pattern with an action. It then stimulates the appropriate nerves, letting the paralyzed walk.

Answer (score 2):

### Some context

The human central nervous system is a fundamentally electrochemical device. If you’ve seen [Michael Reeves hook himself (and others) up to electrodes to remotely “operate” their bodies,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzJrH_DR6SY) it becomes apparent that simple electrical signals designed by an amateur can cause muscles to contract or expand, and that extremely complex electrical signals designed by a millennia-old super intelligence can allow for that superintelligence to remotely control its human body.

### The answer

Assuming that the body you’re talking about is vaguely similar to a human body, the tech would most likely look like **a wide array of electrodes penetrating the muscles that can be individually controlled to trigger muscle contractions and expansions**. This network would have to extend to every muscle in the body and would thus be very comprehensive and complicated, but given thousands of years to design it, I’m sure the superintelligence would come up with something.

### Other notes - appearance, power source

What this electrode network would look like is up to you. Either the electrodes can be very thick and apparent from the outside, or they can be needle-thin and mostly obscured from the outside. But either way, remotely manipulating the human body requires a power source.

This is likely to be a small battery - the electrical signals used by the electrodes needn’t be very powerful. If you want to run your human off the wall (~120VAC at ~15A in the US) for a day, you’re looking at a power source supplying up to 1,800 watts for a day, and therefore 43.2 kilowatt-hours of energy. For reference, most car batteries in 2023-2024 contain about 60-200 kWh, so using today’s standard tech (which you might not be!), you’d need to stuff a small car battery into your organic body.

Of course, there’s room to do this: scoop out the brain! Given that all of the body’s functions are being controlled remotely, you can simply connect the eyes, ears, nerves, etc. to transmitters so that the AI can see and hear and feel through the body, and then remove the rest of the brain and put a battery there.

One small issue: the battery would have an energy capacity of about 720 megajoules of energy, roughly equivalent to 172 kilograms of TNT. Unless you have a way to protect the battery from trauma that might cause it to release this energy and electrocute/incinerate the body, this body won’t be lasting long.

Comment: *"the tech would most likely look like a wide array of electrodes penetrating the muscles that can be individually controlled to trigger muscle contractions and expansions"* [ponders] so, a nervous system then, won't a normal body already have one ;)

Comment: Functionally, yes! But nervous systems are inefficient and use chemical signals in addition to the more-efficient electrical signals. In the name of optimizing the AI's experience, artificially adding a nervous system might be better (and precludes having to develop an interface to the complex bioware that is the naturally-occuring nervous system).

Comment: I was rather under the impression that the "human" experience was rather what the AI was after, an interface to the complex bioware that is the naturally occuring nervous system would seem to be somewhat mandated if that's what it wants to experience, otherwise a human body would seem a bit pointless and a mechanical android should both suffice and be superior if that's not the purpose ;) just a thought.

Comment: Certainly you are correct. I believe (and I may be wrong) that the purpose of the transplant is to obtain human qualia that would otherwise be inaccessible; for this purpose, the original nervous system can be used, but synthesizing the required chemicals on-demand to control the nervous system directly would be more difficult (whereas receiving the chemicals is a relatively simple task).

Comment: Neuralink, no chemicals involved, merely electrical signals sent and received at the point of 'interface', the 'wetware' (the triggered neuron) having been triggered by a small electrical impulse handles all the bits your worrying about to pass the signal on to the next bit of the wetware (the next neuron).. all you need are lots and lots of very fine wires to produce electrical impulses and measure electrical impulses .. have you seen the monkey playing pong? there's no chemical synthesis needed on any of the mechanical end.

Comment: Here you go [Monkey MindPong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsCul1sp4hQ) all they've done is drop a bunch of wires in it's skull to measure the signals it sends to its arm and hand, you'll note the paddle isn't plugged in, that's your received signals from the wetware.

Comment: And here, [Paralysed man walks with .. 'brain bridge' implant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXEBVnrKw64) it picks the signal up from before the break and in response to that stimulates the nerve after the break with an electrical charge, and that's your outgoing signals to the wetware, no chemicals needed, we have all the basis for the input output interface between a brainless body and a computer there.

Comment: some of it for something like this would be patched in directly to the spinal chord and some of it would be threaded through the non-thought centres of the brain that handle processing for things like muscle movement, smell, sound, touch and sight etc. .. you wouldn't need to replace the nervous system and it would probably require a lot more unnecessary coding and invasive procedures to replace the whole nervous system than do it that way .. [Pauses .. Ponders .. Worries people might want to know what he gets up to in the basement if they knew how much he'd thought about this stuff] ;D

Comment: Hormones, sweating, temperature and heartbeat regulation, breathing other then when consciously overriding it and eye blinking etc, all of that is autonomous functions handled by the non-higher-though-centre bits of the brain you leave in, you don't need to worry about them.

Comment: Good point! I suppose as long as those sections of the brain are left intact and connected to oxygen/blood via the lungs/heart, they should be able to handle the simpler autonomous functions as well.

Answer (score 2):

## Possibly (with some caveats)

I'm far from an expert, But... What we call Artificial Intelligence, is normally just a theoretical 'neural network' which is just a series of nodes receiving input and passing output.

Our central nervous system is made of Interneurons which receive signals from the peripheral nervous system and either pass those signals on or block them depending(1). My understanding is that it has 'Plasticity' in these connections meaning it can, form new connections and weakening existing connections (or synapses) based on feedback, likely from hormones.

Now, the nodes in an AI's neural network are significantly more complicated that an individual neuron in your brain, but for scale, a lot of AIs have 10-100 nodes while our brain consists of about 86 billion neurons(2)... To compare scale here that's between 10^1 and 10^2 'nodes' in an AI versus 10^9 in a human head

This means (more or less) that as long as the weighted output function of a given AI-node can be reproduced with an equivilant of around 1 MILLION interneurons and connections (or far less) it's logic could be reproduced with living cells, and that the total mass would probably be equivilant in size and weight to a human brain

#### Some Caveats though...

1> Attempting to rebuild an AI model in neurons would be a massive challenge, (even if you figure out a mapping to use you need the logistics of printing/sculpting billions of delicate microscopic cells WHILE keeping them alive AND constructing an actual spacial configuration that they can each fit and reach what they need to) but you've said this was hundreds of thousands of years ago, with a greater than human intelligence, so it seems... Remotely plausible?

2> ALSO... Human brains evolution is likely highly connected to, and driven by vision, in understanding and reacting to complex foraging situations(3)... An AI developed in the abstract world of a large language model is not suited to understanding and processing the electrical signals from a human eye... A Proof of concept translation of the AI may even a whole new sub-AI to translate it's senses for it or even need to be completely reworked to understand vision let alone other human senses

3> And ALSO ALSO, you still wouldn't be done if you did all of them above, because you'd probably need a THIRD sub-AI to handle physical interaction with the environment (in short, walking, standing, maybe even talking etc) which would probably be analogous to the brainstem and motor cortex)

Finally... Would it be difficult to install and plumb this into a human like body? Actually less than you'd assume. The blood brain barrier means foreign or genetically diverse cells in the brain would likely not be attacked by the immune system and would have access to more or less the right nutrients as long as the mass of, and biological rate of activity is comparable. I mean, connecting the spinal cord is well beyond our current technology, but is dwarfed in comparison to the kind of "3d-brain-printing" we refer to above

1 - https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/human-biology/neuron-nervous-system/a/overview-of-neuron-structure-and-function

2 - [https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/neural-networks-mathematical-replication-brain-ai-cheema#:~:text=Size%3A%20Our%20brain%20consists%20of,network%20is%20about%2010%2D1000](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/neural-networks-mathematical-replication-brain-ai-cheema#:%7E:text=Size%3A%20Our%20brain%20consists%20of,network%20is%20about%2010%2D1000).

3 - https://www.science.org/content/article/fruit-eating-responsible-big-brains

Answer (score 1):

**Frame Challenge**

Rather than having your AI insert itself (or a copy) into a synthetic body, have it instead use real world techniques to subtly shift the desires and will of a person to the will of the AI.

Current recommendation systems (such as ones in TikTok) already have been shown to shape user preferences and ideas [1](https://sloanreview.mit.edu/article/the-hidden-side-effects-of-recommendation-systems/). As your AI is presumably more intelligent than the TikTok recommendation algorithm, it is not a far leap to say it could alter its targets thoughts enough that it could make the person want to do the same things the AI wants. Perhaps even make the person reliant on an app for direction and guidance.

This also has the interesting implication that the person being "manipulated" doesn't need to be synthetic being created by the AI, it can be a normal person with a slighter weaker will.

**Potential Story**

Have your AI introduce an app into the target population, call it FacePamphlet. The AI can then identify a handful of people that it starts serving recommendations to make them think that this planet really should be terraformed, and then they have the ability to make that happen, as long as they keep using FacePamphlet for information of course.

Once terraforming is finished and it is time to put the humans into the simulation, the AI already has a wealth of personalized information from FacePamphlet to put them into an algorithmically perfect feed of stupor and bliss.

[The Hidden Side Effects of Recommendation Systems](https://sloanreview.mit.edu/article/the-hidden-side-effects-of-recommendation-systems/)